# javascript moment.js calculate percentage between two dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the plugin Moment.js and I have html

```
<div class="record-time pull-right" data-date="2013-09-22 20:16:39"
         data-completion-date="2019-08-07 00:00:00">

</div>
```

and I want to calculate the percentage of time elapsed from the data-date attr to the data-completion-date attr, and these dates don't work in firefox or ie, but is fine in chrome.

I can get time from a date using:

```
      moment(new Date(record_time.attr('data-date'))).fromNow()
```

But again it only works in chrome, what am I missing here?
The dates are pulled from a mysql database datetime field.

I get 'NaN' in firefox and ie

**ANSWER:**

```
 var record_time = $(this).find('.record-time');
 var creation_date = $(this).find('.record-time').data('date');
 var completion_date = $(this).find('.record-time').data('completion-date');

 // get percentage completed (now - startDate) / (endDate - startDate)
 now = moment();
 startDate = moment(creation_date);
 endDate = moment(completion_date);
 var percentage_complete = (now - startDate) / (endDate - startDate) * 100;
 var percentage_rounded = (Math.round(percentage_complete * 100) / 100); 
 // percentage rounded to 2 decimal points

 // set the progress bar percentages
 var record_progress = $(this).find('.bar');
 record_progress.css('width', percentage_rounded+'%');
 record_progress.html(percentage_rounded+'% - Completed');
```

Works in latest version of Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery `data('date')` instead of `attr()`

Comment: record_time is the element and its gets the data from the attributes just fine, not sure what you mean

Comment: `data('date')` won't work on some versions of IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), moment.js can parse that format of date string.

Try to parse the date like this instead:

```
moment(record_time.data('date'));
```

Comment: Yep, this is better than using the native Date.

Comment: It continues to work in chrome that way 'moment(record_time.data('date'));' but not firefox or ie

Comment: It's working in all browsers now thanks @Jason P but how to calculate the percentage of time elapsed from the data-date attr to the data-completion-date attr

Comment: Generally speaking, the algorithm would be `(now - startDate) / (endDate - startDate)`

Comment: I have 'var percentage_complete = (moment() - creation_date) / (completion_date - creation_date);'  with the variables from the above div and just get 'NaN' - not my finest moment ;)

Comment: Do a `console.log()` for each of the values and see where things go wrong.

Comment: So long as the dates are all in the same format, that calculation should work?

Comment: Dates don't have a format until you convert them to a string. Is `startDate` a moment object? Search the doc on how to compare two moment dates.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) spec, the expected datestring format is RFC2822 or ISO 8601. Your datestrings are neither of these.

```
Date.parse("2013-09-22 20:16:39") -> NaN in FireFox
Date.parse("2013-09-22T19:16:39Z") -> 1379877399000 in FireFox
```

Comment: I'm pulling the date directly from mysql datetime field, do I need to format it before rendering out the html?